# Is multicolor vision really necessary for CV?

Tags: computer-vision

Having the ability to see 2 or more colors can improve the sensitivity of nuances but greatly increases the complexity of image processing algorithms. I once thought that 3 colors are necessary for the most complex tasks (such as self driving cars) until I learned that colorblind people (who can see only 2 colors) can drive just fine as long as they can read the traffic lights. So I am curious what’s the optimum number of color channels in CV that balances the sensitivity and efficiency?

Comment: It depends on the application. Many design conformance/quality control applications are often fine with black and white, and environmental applications (e.g. forestry) can benefit from multispectral images.

Comment: Great question! I have myself wondered if we're not overfitting when relying on colours for object recognition, when we humans often don't need them. Indeed, we can watch a black and white movie and still get the plot.

Comment: I even asked a question whether a total colorblind can drive normally https://www.quora.com/Other-than-the-inability-to-read-the-traffic-light-signals-can-a-totally-colorblind-driver-unable-to-see-colors-at-all-drive-normally?q=Total%20colorblind%20drive. Unfortunately, total colorblind people always have defective vision other than the inability of seeing colors, so we can’t test whether colors are necessary for driving.